# Limit facebook gift requests per day

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, request, facebook-javascript-sdk

so i am writing this game where life requests can be sent, i have already coded the part where i am am sending life request, but the problem is i can send life requests multiple times to same friend

how can i limit that for once per day

i am coding using java script, and currently i am simply fetching all the requests received and giving lives and then deleting those requests.

i see on other games like CandyCrush, FarmVille, etc, gift requests to a particular friend can be send only once per day, i am looking to do something similar

Answer (score 1):

You could store the timestamp/day of the request in your database and not allow new request for that day. The apprequest dialog offers an "exclude_ids" parameter where you could add the IDs of friends who got a request for that day. I am not using apprequests at the moment, but that´s the only possible solution i can think of.

Or, if you don´t care that the request are being sent several times, you can just check if the user already got a gift for that day when fetching all the requests. That would be a very simple solution.